# Localization (react typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Can someone help me on this.. A want to localize a tsx component/s react typescript-typings.

If there is another way of doing it please show me

My solution contains 2 asp.net WebApi's. The first one use MVC concept and the other one use as front end (using react typescript) and in this project i want to localize the components (.tsx). I want to know how to create a resources file and how to call it on a component/s.

This is a Home.tsx file

```
import * from React from "react"; 
export class Home extends React.Component<{},{}> 
{ render() 
{ return ( <div> <h2>Welcome everyone!!</h2> </div>); 
} }
```

If can't ,is it possible to create a dropdown list and on selecting a langauge the whole text get change??

if have both please show me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it like you want the html content to be localized? The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a library for this:

React intl: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

You can basically just create resource files according to the language (en.json, fr.json, ...)
Hope this helps. You can also create it yourself but that would require a lot of work.

If you just want a simple solution you could try this:

```
    import * as React from "react";
// you can get the browser language through navigator.language
enum Language {
  English,
  French
}
// You can store these in json files (e.g: en.json and fr.json)
const frenchLabels = {
  welcome: "Bienvenue"
};
const englishLabels = {
  welcome: "Welcome"
};

export interface HomeState {
  language: Language;
}
export class Home extends React.Component<{}, HomeState> {
  state = {
    language: Language.English
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({ ...this.state, language: Language.French })
            }
          >
            French
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({ ...this.state, language: Language.French })
            }
          >
            English
          </button>
        </div>{" "}
        <h2>{this.getWelcomeMessage()}</h2>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getWelcomeMessage = (): string => {
    switch (this.state.language) {
      case Language.English:
        return englishLabels.welcome;
      case Language.French:
        return frenchLabels.welcome;
      default:
        return englishLabels.welcome;
    }
  };
}
```